# How to nest several classes in the "Main" class so that the nested classes work?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a method system.start(); that internally calls a chain of actions with different classes. 
When I use this code everything works

```
let view = new View();
let controller = new Controller();
view.facade();
```

But how to make it work from the Main class?

https://codepen.io/igor-sushko/pen/PooWdXM?editors=0011

```
class View {
  facade() {
    let a = controller.get_a();
    console.log(a);
  }
};

class Controller {
  get_a() {
    return "Taked param from another class";
  }
};

// let view = new View();
// let controller = new Controller();
// view.facade();

class Main {
  constructor(p) {
    this.view = p.view;
    this.controller = p.controller;
  }


  start() {
    console.log("worked!")
    this.view.facade();
  }
};

let system = new Main({ view: new View(), controller: new Controller() });

system.start();
```

Comment: If you look at the error log it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: You need to pass the controller to the view, for instance in the constructor of `Main`. Like `this.view.controller = p.controller;`. In the View's method, use `this.controller` instead of `controller`.

Comment: In your first code snippet `controller` is global, so `View` knows what `controller` is. However, this isn't the case for your second snippet

Comment: @ChrisG amaizing! thank you very mach!

Comment: What's really interesting about that `codepen` is it's not showing some errors in it's `console`.. Bug maybe.. ?  ps.  Use your browsers console instead, it's better anyway..

Comment: @Keith I will, thank you! :)

Comment: @NickParsons thanks! I just work on an internship, and there are many things that I will need to learn